# Adding DataGridView to each TabPage in tabControl

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having some problem with adding dataGridView to each TabPage.

I'm adding TabPages from the list 
e.g

```
        List<string> lista = new List<string>();
        lista.Add("test1");
        lista.Add("test2");
        lista.Add("test3");

        foreach (var p in lista)
        {
            tabControl_Roz.TabPages.Add(p);

        }
```

And now i want to add DataGridView for each of them. DataGridView should be named :

```
       dataGridView_p
```

Where p is tabPage name.
Can someone tell me how can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the DataGridView to the TabPage you created. For this you better use a for loop instead of foreach...

```
    List<string> lista = new List<string>();
    lista.Add("test1");
    lista.Add("test2");
    lista.Add("test3");

    for(int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
    {
        tabControl_Roz.TabPages.Add(lista[i]);
        tabControl_Roz.TabPages[i].Controls.Add(new DataGridView(){
            Name="dataGridView_" + lista[i],
            Dock=DockStyle.Fill});
    }
```

To fill the DataSource you can either add it while creating the datagridview:

```
tabControl_Roz.TabPages[i].Controls.Add(new DataGridView(){
            Name="dataGridView_" + lista[i],
            Dock=DockStyle.Fill,
            DataSource = xxx});
```

Or as an example for the first TabPage (index == 0):

```
int dataGridViewIndex = tabControl_Roz.TabPages[0].Controls.IndexOfKey("dataGridView_" + "test1");
if(dataGridViewIndex >= 0)
{
    DataGridView myTabGridView = tabControl_Roz.TabPages[0].Controls[dataGridViewIndex] as DataGridView;
    if(myTabGridView != null)
    {
        myTabGridView.DataSource = xxx;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but there is another problem, how can I use dataGridView for example : dataGridView.test1.dataSource = dataTable. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The Problem is you cannot Access the DataGridView by Name as you are used to in designtime. The Compiler does not know how the DataGridView is named when you add it in runtime. You have to manually search it by name  in the control collection of the TabPage. See edited answer

Comment: Im getting error with .Where in TabPages[0].Controls.Where  which tells me that Collection not contain a definition for "Where"

Comment: Yes. I just noticed that this is not possible with a ControlCollection. I'm updating the answer in a Minute.